# SQL: Reference Column Value in Subquery and Vice Versa

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery, where-clause

Lets say I am working on a query that looks something like this:

```
 update user as u 
   set u.city = (
    select min(c1.id) 
       from (
         select c1.id 
           from city c1 
          where c1.name = (
            select c2.name 
              from city c2 where c2.id = u.city)) as duplicates);
```

Which is meant to dedupe the city list in my user table to have the smallest city id in the city table of all id's which share the same city name.  Hence the deduping. However, I get this error:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'u.city' in 'where clause'
```

My user table definitely does have a city column, ie

```
mysql> describe user;
+----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                         | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| first_name                 | varchar(64)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| last_name                  | varchar(64)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
...
| city                       | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
...
+----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
36 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So I see two interestng things about this query, the user table city column value (u.city) is referred to in the subquery, and the city id from the city table is used in the middle query, (select min(c1.id)).  How do I make this work?

Comment: when writing sub-queries think about the scope and how the query will be processed. IE: sub-queries are processed before the outer query so anything in the sub-query that depends on the outer query will fail. You have to shift your thinking and write queries from the inside out not the outside in.

Comment: can you just order the second query by id and use LIMIT to only return one row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think such a query is more easily written using explicit `join`s rather than nested queries:

```
update user u join
       city c
       on u.city = c.city join
       (select name, min(id) as minid
        from city
        group by name
       ) cmin
       on cmin.name = c.name
    set u.city = cmin.minid;
```

MySQL also seems to have a limit on how deep a nesting can go on correlated references, although I haven't found this limit documented anywhere.

Comment: I believe that you can nest arbitrarily deep, but that the scope of correlated references is one level only.  This is (I believe) the reason that twice-nested queries get around MySQL's limitation of not being able to update a table from a query that also references that same table.

Comment: In the end I went with creating a temporary table to hold the ids-to-be-deduped. Something like `create temporary table city_id_deduplication_map (
    city_id bigint(20),
    canonical_id bigint(20),
    unique(city_id)
);` And then joined / updated off of this table.  Made life simpler and the SQL easier to look at.  Thanks for the answer.  Also apparently mysql does not compare nulls nicely so the equality check `u.city = c.city` needs to be `u.city = c.city or (u.city is null and  c.city is null)`

Comment: @MatBailie . . . I believe that too.  Unfortunately, I cannot find the documentation reference (which would be most appropriate at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/correlated-subqueries.html).

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:-

```
UPDATE user 
INNER JOIN
(             
    SELECT u.city, MIN(c1.id) AS min_city
    FROM user u
    INNER JOIN city c2 ON c2.id = u.city
    INNER JOIN city.c1 ON c1.name = c2.name
    GROUP BY u.city
) sub1
ON u.city = sub1.city
SET u.city = sub1.min_city
```